# How to refresh/update pin location every x secs on Google map using xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am working on xamarin based mobile app.I need to retrieve data from server about user location and update the user location on maps every x seconds.I am storing user lat and lon on server but when I am retrieving the coordinates from server the latest pin is not rendered on map.only first.time the pin is rendered then after even if position of lat and lon changes the pin remains as it is and not rendered on new location.Can somebody provide the solution for same.

Please find code below
This piece of code is used to get position every 10 seconds

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
                     {
                         bool CallAgain = true;
                         lblStatus.IsVisible = false;
                         mapVM.getGpsPosition().ContinueWith((Task<ApiResponseModel.DriverLocationDetailsResponseModel> t) =>
                         {
                             if (t.Result.status == DriverStatus.Running.ToString() || t.Result.status == DriverStatus.Started.ToString())
                             {
                                 RedrawMap(t.Result.lat, t.Result.lon);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 ParentMaps.IsVisible = false;
                                 lblStatus.IsVisible = true;
                                 lblStatus.Text = "Driver has stopped the journey";
                                 CallAgain = false;
                             }

                         });
                         return CallAgain;
                     });
```

This piece of code is used to draw pins on maps

```
private void RedrawMap(double lat, double lon)
{
    var pin = new CustomPin
    {
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(lat, lon),
        Label = "Current Location",
        Id = "Xamarin"
    };

    DriverMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
    if (DriverMap.Pins.Count > 0)
    {
        DriverMap.Pins.Clear();
    }
    DriverMap.Pins.Add(pin);
    DriverMap.MoveToRegion(
            MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new 
            Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(lat, lon), 
            Distance.FromMiles(0.1))
            );
  }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason I have posted code can you take a look and guide me how to resolve issue.

Answer (score 1):

you could make a timer,ervery x seconds to clean the pins and reload the new pins

Reference ： https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/118999/refresh-pins-positions-in-google-maps